# Does the MongoDb C# driver query support Except()?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

```
var querycodes= new string[] {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
var query = collection.AsQueryable<Source>()
                      .Where(d => (d.codes.Count == querycodes.Count() &&
                                  !d.codes.Except(querycodes).Any()));
```

It's throwing error:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: Enumerable.Count(Enumerable.Except(d.codes, String[]:{ "aaa", "bbb" ... })).

How can I achieve query targets?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems the official driver does not currently support `Except()` - it's not on the list [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/#csharp-driver-linq-tutorial)

There are a bunch of [non-standard extensions like `In` (maps to $in)](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/) - you can probably use one of these as a work around. (I couldn't see `$nin` however possibly `!In` will be mapped to `$nin`?)

As a last resort, you may need to materialize part of the collection and apply the `Except` in memory with Linq to Objects?

**Edit** Here's the last resort where the entire collection is pulled into memory - This is not recommended if you have a large number of objects.

```
var querycodes= new string[] {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
var query = collection.AsQueryable<Source>()
                      .ToList()
                      .Where(d => (d.codes.Count == querycodes.Count() &&
                                  !d.codes.Except(querycodes).Any()));
```

Or better still, since `Count()` is implemented (as `$size`), is to do a first pass filter in Mongo and then a second pass in memory:

```
var querycodes= new string[] {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
var query = collection.AsQueryable<Source>()
                      .Where(d => d.codes.Count == querycodes.Count())
                      .ToList()
                      .Where(d => !d.codes.Except(querycodes).Any()));
```

Comment: thanks, actually i was apply the Except in memory with Linq to Objects